# Check to see if capital letters exist in string

Tags: python

I was supposed to write a program that verifies a username. The username must consist of at least 8-15 letters, no alphanumeric values. So, you can only have numbers and letters. You can't have numbers at the beginning or the end. And, You MUST have at least one capital and lower case letter and at least one number. I got how to do everything but how to get the program to check to see if it contains any capital letters. I tried to do the " if not in " but no luck. This is what I have so far.

```
username = input("please enter a name: ")
for i in username:
    while len(username) < 8 or len(username) > 15:
        print("Password is too long or too short")
        username = input("please enter a name: ")

    j = 31
    while j < 47:
        j += 1
        while chr(j) in i:
            print("No alphanumeric values allowed.")
            username = input("please enter a name: ")
    k = 57
    while k < 64:
        k += 1
        while chr(k) in i:
            print("No alphanumeric values allowed.")
            username = input("please enter a name: ")
    l = 47
    while l < 57:
        l += 1
        while chr(l) in username[0]:
            print("you cannot have a number in the beggining")
            username = input("please enter a name: ")

        while chr(l) in username[-1]:
            print("you cannot have a number in the end")
            username = input("please enter a name: ")
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: This earlier post should help you out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602111/how-to-search-for-a-capital-letter-within-a-string-and-return-the-list-of-words

Comment: Why are you using key codes? There is obviously a better way to do this, you know.

Comment: You say it must have no alphanumeric values and only have letters and numbers? These statements are contradictory, I assume you meant it must have ***ONLY*** alphanumeric values?

Comment: ya my bad. I meant it can have only alphanumeric values

Comment: @RoryDaulton I am trying to write a code that can check my input and see if it has any capital letters and lower case letters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any with a generator to test if the string has a capital letter

```
testString = "abjKcf"
print(any(x.isupper() for x in testString)) #true
```

## Good Solution

As for addressing a solution to your problem, welcome to the world of generator expressions and assertions

```
while True:
    testString = input()
    try:
        assert 8 <= len(testString) <= 15, "String must be between 8 and 15 characters"
        assert all(x.isalnum() for x in testString), "String must be alphanumeric"
        assert any(x.isupper() for x in testString), "String must contain one capital"
        assert any(x.islower() for x in testString), "String must contain one lowercase"
        assert any(x.isdigit() for x in testString), "String must contain one digit"
        assert testString[0].isdigit() == False, "No numbers at start"
        assert testString[-1].isdigit() == False, "No numbers at end"
        break #if we haven't hit any errors then the username fits the criterion
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

## Really ugly solution (as requested)

Basically you set up some booleans and try to disprove them by looping through every character and checking if it meets some conditions

```
while True:
    testString = input()

    allAlphaNumeric = True
    oneCapital = False
    oneLowerCase = False
    oneDigit = False

    for letter in testString:
        if not letter.isalnum():
            oneAlphaNumeric = False
        if letter.isupper():
            oneCapital = True
        if letter.islower():
            oneLowerCase = True
        if letter.isdigit():
            oneDigit = True

    numberAtStart = testString[0].isdigit()
    numberAtEnd = testString[-1].isdigit()

    if allAlphaNumeric and oneCapital and oneLowerCase and oneDigit and not numberAtEnd and not numberAtStart:
        break

    if not 8 <= len(testString) <= 15:
        print("String must be between 8 and 15 characters")
    if not allAlphaNumeric:
        print("Your string must be alphanumeric!")
    if not oneCapital:
        print("Your string must contain at least one capital letter")
    if not oneLowerCase:
        print("Your string must contain atleast one lowercase letter")
    if not oneDigit:
        print("Your string must contain atleast one digit")
    if numberAtStart:
        print("You cannot have a number at the start")
    if numberAtEnd:
        print("You cannot have a number at the end")
```

Comment: If it does not have a capital letter, or a lower case letter, or at least one number, then the program needs to reprompt the user.

Comment: is there any other way lol ? like can you take the input username, put it through a loop and check to see if there is ATLEAST one capital letter ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what this code is doing. Do you not like it because it's so simplified down? You want old fashioned ugly for loops? This is essentially checking every single letter and making sure one is capital, it's just behind the scenes

Comment: hahaha i have not learned stuff that advanced yet, so like i still do not know what it exactly is.

Comment: how would i achieve the same result using an ugly for loop hahaha

Comment: Do you wanna not use assertions either? or are those allowed?

Comment: assertions aren't allowed